# I can't view any posts on GDSE today

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions

I was browsing, as I usually do, answering, commenting, etc.

I'll admit, I'm working on a badge that involves a lot of voting, so I've been trying to view as many questions/answers as possible, up and down voting as I see fit.

Now, when I try to view a question, I get this error screen:

[image: error]

Everything else on the site works fine, I can click on and navigate through every other area.  When I try to view a question, though, I get the error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This was a problem network wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277523/216955), it should be fixed now.

> This was a bug in pathing that should never be allowed to bring down question pages anyway - a fix has been deployed and I'll be preventing that code from causing such drastic issues ever again in my next commit.